# Keyboard Shortcuts in Edit Mode gone

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut

I just updated to Blender 4.0 and now the keyboard shortcuts I use the most in Edit Mode are no longer working and I can't find how to get them back.
A to select all, D and del to delete, S for scale, g for grab, r for rotate. 1-vertex select, 2-edge select, 3-face select.
How do I get these shortcuts back?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Try to do a factory reset, inside File menu. Also, I'm not sure that D is for delete, but X and "Del" are, you could also rearrange the shortcuts inside Edit >preferences

Comment: Yeah, miss report on my part, I meant x for delete.

Comment: I was able to get functionality back by loading factory preferences under Edit>Preferences then the Save/Load menu at the bottom left of the window.